# Java File.createNewFile() much slower than just FileOutputStream

Tags: java

I am observing an interesting performance degradation when using File.createNewFile() or File.createTempFile().  The following code creates 48 threads, each of which writes about 128MB of data to a different file. If I run the code as is, it takes about 60 seconds on my particular machine.  If I run the code exactly as is, except I comment out the f.createTempFile() call then it takes around 5 seconds.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public final class TestFile implements Runnable {
  public void run() {
    byte[] b = new byte[128205100];
    Arrays.fill(b, (byte)10);

    try {
      File f = new File("/tmp/test", UUID.randomUUID().toString());

      // If I comment the following f.createNewFile() then the code takes
      // 5 seconds rather than 60 to execute. 
      f.createNewFile();

      FileOutputStream fOutputStream =  new FileOutputStream(f);
      BufferedOutputStream fBufStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fOutputStream, 32768);
      fBufStream.write(b);
      fBufStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ExecutorService executorPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(48);
    for (int counter=0; counter < 48; counter++) {
       executorPool.execute(new TestFile());
    }
    try {
      executorPool.shutdown();
      executorPool.awaitTermination(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.err.println("Caught InterruptedException: " + e.getMessage());
    }       
  }
}
```

Using jstack, I can see that when running the code above all the threads end up spending most of their time in close0().  This function is unfortunately native :-/  Any idea where I find the source for it?

```
"Thread-47" #68 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f21001de800 nid=0x4eb4 runnable [0x00007f209edec000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.close0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.access$000(FileOutputStream.java:53)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream$1.close(FileOutputStream.java:356)
        at java.io.FileDescriptor.closeAll(FileDescriptor.java:212)
        - locked <0x00000005908ad628> (a java.io.FileDescriptor)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.close(FileOutputStream.java:354)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
        at TestFile.run(TestFile.java:19)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My guess is that someone somewhere (inside the native close0 ?) is issuing a sync, but I am not finding it.  I have tested this on a few machines, and in some of them I don't see the degradation.  So this is possibly configuration or environmental based.

I am running on Ubuntu using Java 8.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I can't say why it is *that much* slower, but [if you look at the source of `FileOutputStream`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/FileOutputStream.java#194), all it uses from the `File` parameter is its name and the check of the path's validity: it overwrites the file if it already exists anyway. So, it's just unnecessary to create it first.

Comment: agree with Turner, createnewfile checks for system's securityManager, where as FileOutputStream just blidly tries to write

Comment: This is not a file permission issue, since the file is created with the same permission (rw) either way.  It is also not a case of the data still requiring a flush, since I get the same behaviour if I add fStream.flush() just prior to the fStream.close().

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner and nafas.  I don't think it's the security manager, since FileOutputStream(File, boolean) also access it and checkWrite().  I am trying to understand what's causing the difference because a module that we are using in hadoop is calling the createNewFile or createTempFile and this results in significant degradation on some of our systems.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple. `File.createNewFile()` searches for a file by that name, and either creates a new file if it doesn't exist, or fails, which you are correctly ignoring, as it doesn't matter in the least whether it succeeded or not. `new FileOutputStream()` searches for any existing file by the same name, deletes it, and creates a new file.

It is evident therefore that `File.createNewFile()` is a complete waste of time when it is followed by `new FileOutputStream()`, as it forces the operating system to:

1. Search for the file.
2. Create it if it doesn't exist, or fail.
3. Search for the file.
4. Delete it if it exists.
5. Create it.

Clearly (1) and (2) are a waste of time, and force (4) to happen when it may not have needed to.

Solution: don't call `File.createNewFile()` before `new FileOutputStream(...)`. Or `new FileWriter(...)` for that matter, or `new PrintStream/PrintWriter(...)` either. There is nothing to be gained, and time and space to be wasted.

Comment: I think there is more to it then this.  I can see the files created and containing the newly written data (so it has been flushed to disk) within a few seconds.  Then the threads sit and wait inside close() for another 50 odd seconds.  I am also not able to reproduce this on every system.

Comment: So therefore `File.createNewFile()` has nothing to do with it. That only creates empty files, and `new FileOutputStream()` will replace those anyway. Just remove it. You don't need it, it wastes space and time, and according to your observations it somehow wastes a *lot* of time. Or else you're barking up the wrong tree altogether, in which case you should still remove it for the reasons I stated.